# How to log off Twitter on all devices?

Tags: twitter, passwords, mobile

I logged on to my Twitter on my dad's computer once and forgot to log off. He now constantly checks my Twitter to see if there is any activity because he does not know I have an iPod.  And he knows something is up because there are tweets in the morning and he thinks I'm using his computer.

How do I log him out of my Twitter without having to go on to his computer?

Answer (score 0):

Change your password! it will log out your account from any device that has been logged in any device.

Comment: Any source for this information?

Comment: From my experience! :-|
Changed password from web, then reloaded already logged-in page in my mobile browser. and it redirected to https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new